# Xcode: Storyboards too cluttered and 'busy

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ide, development-environment

In **Xcode**, I am experiencing a user problem which is halting the development of my app because the UI is becoming difficult to manage. The **storyboards are getting cluttered with different objects and other bits and pieces**.

As I am developing *my first app*, I have found storyboards *easy to use*, but looking back now I am *regretting* that decision. In my main view, **a lot of things happen**, with different images, text fields, labels, touch to begin buttons e.t.c, and this is slightly annoying as the screen becomes *really busy and clustered*.

Here is an example (please could you be kind enough to *excuse the cringy images*, they're still being designed):

[image: cluttered]

So I was wondering, is there the functionality to *view a storyboard multiple times*, more specifically to have *different layers* which you can work with one by one?

If not, is there an **easy way to get round cluttered storyboards**?

**Thank you** in advance!

**Will arcofclark**

Comment: You can split a project into multiple storyboards and load them as needed.

Comment: @AnnaDickinson Thank you for the suggestion, do you think you could give an answer explaining?

Comment: Rather than putting a UIImageView on the storyboard, why don't you make it in code. Buttons that go to different view controllers I tend to use the storyboard, but when it comes to making an image or putting in a background I stick to code, and it's very easy to make it in the code.

Comment: Google "multiple UIStoryboards" for a bunch of examples and other SO answers.

Comment: Are you saying that a particular scene is getting too busy (in which case, the multiple storyboards counsel is not a great idea) or that you have too many scenes in a particular storyboard? If it's the former, i.e. if you have a single scene with is serving different purposes (sometimes one set of controls is visible, other times another set of controls is visible), you might break those into separate scenes, each with its own view controller. Then you can use view controller containment (with a container view) to choose which scene will be visible at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic solution here. Storyboards can indeed get unwieldy. That said, your entire application need not be contained within a single storyboard.  You can have multiple storyboards that you stitch together in code.

For instance you could have an entry storyboard that contains:

- A welcome screen with Create Account / Login buttons
- A transition to a create account view controller
- A transition to a login view controller
- A transition to a forgot password view controller

Then in each case where you have successfully logged in or created a user account, you can handle it in code to present a view controller from a separate storyboard altogether:

```
func didRecognizeUser(user: User) {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(named: "AppStoryboard")
  let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController
  self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Another case that might help is breaking apart the different sections of your app (for instance tabs in a tab bar controller) as each their own storyboard.

It makes it a little easier to work inside of a storyboard when it only contains a handful of controllers.  Once you start getting above 4 or 5 controllers, it becomes hard to manage (for me).

Hope this helps.